# Добавить элемент N раз в Linq

Tags: c#, linq

На форму заказа (Order) нужно добавить пять позиций (OrderPosition), делаю это в цикле:

```
var order = new Order();

var orderPositions = new List<OrderPositions>();

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    orderPositions.Add(new OrderPositions {Discount = 0M, ... });

order.OrderPositions = orderPositions;
```

А можно ли цикл for заменить linq-выражением, желательно без библиотеки MoreLinq?

Comment: А зачем? Ситуация примерно как с ForEach / foreach - вариант с for как минимум короче, чем с Enumerable.Range. А я бы сказал - еще и читабельнее :)

Comment: @PashaPash linq-вариант - одна строчка (сразу присвоил Enumerable.Range), цикл - шесть (без пустых строк - 4). Производительность некритична. Не то, чтобы я фанатик "адских linq-однострочников", но тут мне цикл нравится меньше.

Comment: @PashaPash, как вариант - просто знать что можно сделать это и таким способом. Не пригодится в этом конкретном примере - пригодится в другом.

Comment: И мне нравится через Range, но я бы писал через for, так как если код будут читать джуниоры, то у них от такого башню может сорвать :) А с for все будет понятно даже самому упоротому джуниору

Comment: Кстати, если хочется краткости, можно вместо `Enumerable.Range(0, 5)` написать что-то вроде `new int[5]`, но да, здесь будет фактически создаваться массив, что может быть накладно при большом `N`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Используйте [`Enumerable.Range()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
orderPositions.AddRange(
    Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
              .Select(i => new OrderPositions { Discount = 0M, ... }));
```

Здесь в `Select` вы можете использовать `i` также, как в своем цикле.

Ну и в итоге ваш фрагмент можно переписать так:

```
var order = new Order();
order.OrderPositions =
    Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
              .Select(i => new OrderPositions { Discount = 0M, ... })
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Я вообще воспользовался object initializer и мне не нужен был .ToList - там уже IEnumerable - это скорее к комментарию PashaPash о числе строк.

Comment: Хм, а кто материализует перечисление? У вас там EF или что?

Comment: object initializer хорошо, но в одну строчку, имхо, слишком уж длинно будет, а в несколько - лишние строчки (хотя студия всеми силами нас склоняет к object initializer)